# How do I disable pseudo film perforation (movie strip overlay) on video thumbnail previews?

Tags: nautilus, previews

That doesn't disturb when medium-size icons are shown (though hide some part of image):
[image]

But using small icons, sometimes all I can see is just pseuso film frame:
[image]